# is there any application that converts a PyQt (with syntax in Python) project to a Qt (with syntax in C++ ) project?

Tags: c++, python, qt, pyqt, pyqt4

Can someone tell whether there is any application that converts a PyQt4 (with syntax in Python) project to a Qt4 (with syntax in C++) project?

This will help people to switch from using a GPL non-commercial license in case of PyQt to a much liberal LGPL non-commercial license in case of Qt!

Comment: There is an early project called py2cpp but I don't think it can handle something that complex. Is there some limitation in Python that you are hoping to avoid in C++?

Comment: If the license is your concern, check out [PySide](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Category:LanguageBindings::PySide) and stay in Python.

Comment: Janne Karila:  PySide is not as supported as PyQt and Qt.

Comment: You are probably out of luck.  Most of the function calls to Qt in PyQt can be translated almost directly, but besides that you are looking at a lot of translation work ahead of you.  But it is probably easier than Matlab to C/C++.  Matlab has array indexing that starts at one instead of zero.

Comment: SIP is what is used to make PyQt bindings.  There is more information here: http://wiki.python.org/moin/SIP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use PySide. It's about 99.8 % compatible with PyQt, except for Signals and Slots.

Replace every occurence of PyQt4 with PySide in your project, then replace pyqtSignal with Qt.Signal and pyqtSlot with Qt.Slot.

It should work out of the box.

Many projects support both PyQt and PySide because there is virtually no difference between the two…